# How to set notification sound volume programmatically?

Tags: android, notifications, android-audiomanager

I have this method in my main activity

```
private void beep()
{
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0,
            AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI + AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
    Uri notification = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(),
            notification);
    r.play();
}
```

As I understand, notification sound volume should be regulated by STREAM_NOTIFICATION. But notification always plays with the same volume despite that volume number in setStreamVolume method. Why is that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I went another way. It's not exactly answer to my question but appropriate one. When I play notification in STREAM_MUSIC everything is fine. So notification plays exactly with volume I pass as parameter to the function

```
private void beep(int volume)
{
    AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, volume, 0);

    Uri notification = RingtoneManager
            .getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

    MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notification);
    player.start();
}
```

Comment: The sound is still playing when notification is off from device settings. Is anybody facing this issue using the above code? Note - I'm using GCM latest library.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, I hope you realize that you are attempting to play two notifications right after each other, so there might be a conflict about that. `AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND` and `r.play()` will both try playing the sound. It is usually enough to give user one type of information, either by UI or by playing the beep with new volume. I suggest you delete one of the flags. If you don't need any, just give it 0.

Coming to the main question, I am not sure if you can set volume level to 0. Try putting 1, like

```
manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 1, AudioManager.FLAG_SHOW_UI);
```

If you want to mute the notification, try using [setStreamMute](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setStreamMute%28int,%20boolean%29), which is equivalent to setting the volume to 0.

Comment: Doesn't help. I removed both flags, but notification is still played with the same volume when I put **1** or **7**

Comment: Did you add MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS permission into your manifest file?

Comment: No. Nothing changed after I added this section in manifest -  <permission android:name="MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" >
    </permission>

Comment: Ok, keep that permission because you will need it. Can you please go to Settings/Sounds/Volumes in your phone and see if your notification volume is linked to your ringer volume? If yes, unlink them and try again.

Comment: What do you mean under 'ringer'? My main ringtone?

Comment: Yes, your ringtone volume, the thing you hear when someone calls you.

Comment: Notification and ringtone volume has different values

Comment: When you change it programatically, do you see it reflected on your phone settings also?

Comment: Yes. Notification volume in settings has changed, but I hear always the same volume of notification

Comment: Then the last thing you can do is to play a notification volume on your phone (not in your code) and see if you hear the same volume. If not, you might want to check the part of your code where you are playing the notification sound.

Answer (score 0):

For my case eventually this seemed to be working.
It would make your audio volume relative to the stream current volume but it was useful for my need.

```
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), notificationUri);
player.setVolume(toneLevel, toneLevel);
```

toneLevel is between 0.0 - 1.0 so you don't even need to find the range of your stream..

Answer (score -2):

Write a function as follow, or copy and paste the following,

```
public void ringtone() {
    try {
        Uri notification = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), notification);
        r.play();
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

and call `ringtone()` when you want to make a beep notification.

Comment: original question is about volume... he has almost exact snippet as this one so this has nothing to do with the volume.